# Ics file is "sending update" instead of creating a "send"

Tags: javascript, outlook, icalendar

I have this meeting appointment i'm trying to send from an `.ics` file.
This is the data

```js
"BEGIN:VCALENDAR\n" +
"CALSCALE:GREGORIAN\n" +
"METHOD:PUBLISH\n" +
"PRODID:-//Send project Invite//EN\n" +
"VERSION:2.0\n" +
"BEGIN:VEVENT\n" +
"UID:gestionprojetsCalendarInvite\n" +
"DTSTART;VALUE=DATE-TIME:" +
convertDate(startDate) +
"\n" +
"DTEND;VALUE=DATE-TIME:" +
convertDate(endDate) +
"\n" +
"SUMMARY:" +
subject +
"\n" +
"DESCRIPTION:" +
description +
"\n" +
"LOCATION:" +
location +
"\n" +
to.filter(o => o != '').map(o => "ATTENDEE;MAILTO:" + o.email).join("\n") +
"\n" +
"BEGIN:VALARM" +
"\n" +
"TRIGGER:-PT15M" +
"\n" +
"ACTION:DISPLAY" +
"\n" +
"DESCRIPTION:Reminder" +
"\n" +
"END:VALARM\n" +
"END:VEVENT\n" +
"END:VCALENDAR";
```

I want to know why, when I open the `.ics` file, it's saying `"send update`" instead of `"send"`.

What I get :

[image: what i get]

What I want :

[image: What I want]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it’s because you have static UID for all `.ics` you generated. `"UID:gestionprojetsCalendarInvite\n"`

UID aka unique ID, is supposed to uniquely represent a calendar event. When you open an ics file containing duplicated UID, your app (Outlook I guess?) thinks you want to update an existing event, not creating a new one.

Try give it a different UID to see if that solves your problem.

Ref: https://icalendar.org/New-Properties-for-iCalendar-RFC-7986/5-3-uid-property.html

Comment: I had already tried that with adding a number after the uid, this time, I tried with real UUID generation and still didn't work. `"UID:55ccc5f1-3e78-4db3-b3e6-2dc6ed4a2f25\n" `